# Application symbol with CPack

Tags: windows, image, cmake, nsis, cpack

I am trying to specify an image which is used by CPack/NSIS to create an application symbol. It should be displayed in the start menu folder, as desktop icon and in the apps & features menu.
What I know so far is:

```
# Icon displayed inside the installer on top left
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_ICON ""${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/images\\\\Icon.bmp")
# Icon visible in Taskbar at installation, same for CPACK_NSIS_MUI_UNIICON 
set(CPACK_NSIS_MUI_ICON "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/images/Install_Icon.ico")
```

I already tried the parameters CPACK_NSIS_MUI_HEADERIMAGE,

```
set(CPACK_NSIS_INSTALLED_ICON_NAME bin\\\\${PROJECT_NAME}.exe)
```

and everything on google page 1+2 what get's shown for a combination of cpack, icon, desktop shortcut, ...
Does anyone know how this works? Or is a special format/size needed?

Comment: Setting the application icon (i.e. for your executable) is platform specific AFAIK. Setting the application icon is completely separate from setting the icon(s) used an NSIS based installer via CPack, which is what the code you posted is doing.

Comment: What do you mean by "Application symbol"? The icon of your .exe?

Comment: Yes, the symbol of the .exe. Like the "e" of Internet explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to the comment of @Developer Paul. CPack and NSIS are misleading here because the different options to link to icons and images suggest that it's a setting you make through them.
Actually the application icon is set with a resource file (.rc) under windows, so you have 3 files: your CMakeLists.txt, the Icon.ico and the AppIcon.rc.

In your CMakeLists.txt link to the .rc file

```
add_executable("${PROJECT_NAME}" helloworld.cpp AppIcon.rc)
```

The .rc contains only the link to your .ico, like this:

```
IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE "images/icon.ico"
```

In my case I have a separate *images* folder in my project folder.
And that's basically it. BUT this solution seems to work only for windows, for Linux you have to do it differently.

Comment: This is for Qt. or what about GTK?